# Formatting problems for strings representing numbers, especially integers

Tags: php, casting, formatting

This is quite a simple problem, but I don't see a simple and straight forward solution.

I have values that represent numeric values, but are strings. Examples: `0.0, 1.0, 10.0, 1.1`.
Most time they represent integers, but there can be fractions.

I want to display these numbers as `0, 1, 10, 1.1`.

I thought of these straight forward solutions, but they do not account for the occasional fractions:

```
$val = (int) val;
--OR--
$val = sprintf('%d', $val);
```

Obviously there would be long solutions, that test if the number is an integer before formatting, but I'm looking for something simple, as short as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this simple trick:

```
echo 0.0 + 0;
echo 1.0 + 0;
echo 10.0 + 0;
echo 1.1 + 0;
```

this is equivalent to casting to float with

```
(float)$num
```

or

```
floatval($num)
```

Comment: Thanks, I prefer the solution `(float) $val`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$val = preg_match("/\.0$/", $number_string) ? (int)$number_string : (float)$number_string;
```

It uses a regular expression on the original string to match a `.0` ending, and if there is a match, type casts the string value to an integer, otherwise casts the value to a float.